# Why time complexity for permutation algorithm is n*n! and not n^3 * n!?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, permutation

Author claims that time complexity of this permutation algorithm:

```
from collections import deque

def find_permutations(nums):
    
    nums_l = len(nums)
    perms = deque()
    perms.append([])
    
    for num in nums:                     # (1)
        for _ in range(len(perms)):      # (2)
            perm = perms.popleft() 
            for j in range(len(perm)+1): # (3)
                new_perm = list(perm)    # (4)
                new_perm.insert(j, num)  # (5)
                perms.append(new_perm)   # (6)
    
    return perms
```

is `n*n!`

But I don't understand why. Here is my computation of time complexity for each line of code:

```
(1): len(nums) ~ n
(2): len(perms) ~ n!
(3): len(perm) ~ n
(4): n
(5): n
(6): n
```

So total Time complexity is:

```
n * n! * n * (n + n + n) ~ n^3 * n!
```

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting to the main issue, there is a minor error for step (6): `append` is O(1). But that doesn't influence the overall complexity.

Your analysis goes wrong at step (2):

```
for _ in range(len(perms)):
```

This does not perform O(n!) iterations. The first time it even only executes 1 iteration, the second time still 1 iteration, and the third time 2 iterations, then 2 * 3, then 2 * 3 * 4, ... and the last time (n-1)! iterations.

Then there is also an overestimation at step (3):

```
for j in range(len(perm)+1)
```

The size of `perm` is initially small (corresponding to the loop of step 2): first the permutation(s) have size 0, then in the next iteration of the outer loop they have size 1, ... then 2, ... up to n-1.

So for the *total* number of iterations of the inner loop, we have this sum:

1 * 1 + 1 * 2 + 2 * 3 + (2 * 3) * 4 + ... + k! + ... n!

An easier way to look at this is to realise that, at each iteration of the outer loop, this code produces all permutations that are one item longer than in its previous iteration. So in the first iteration you get all permutations of size 1 (using the first input value), in the second iteration you get all permutations of size 2 (using the two first input values), ...etc. It is a bottom-up approach. Also notice that `popLeft` is executed the right number of times to remove all permutations of the previous (outer) iteration, while `append` is executed for all new permutations (which only get popped in the next outer iteration).

So we can now easily see that `append` is executed this number of times:

1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + ... + n! = O(n!)

If we now include into that the complexity of step 4 (which "absorbs" the complexity of step 5), then we get:

1.1! + 2.2! + 3.3! + 4.4! + ... + n.n! = O(n.n!)

Comment: What about complexity of step 1? It should be O(n) as well. So it looks like total complexity is going to be O(n.n.n!), right? Thanks.

Comment: No, step 1 is incorporated in when I wrote *"for the **total** number of iterations of the inner loop"* -- I updated a phrase to indicate that the outer loop is taken into account.

Comment: It looks like I finally understand it.  If we compare permutation algorithm to something with time complexity n^2 e.g. [i for i in range(n) for j in range(n)] the difference is that for permutation algorithm we have a different number of exceptions on each step so time complexity will be just complexity of the last step (n!).  But for n^2 algorithm, we have n execution for each outer loop e.g. for n =5: O(5+5+5+5+5) = O(5*5) or O(n^2). To compare it to the permutation algorithm we have time complexity O(1! + 2! + 3! + 4! +...) and the final complexity will be just the last step complexity (n!)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm generates permutations by inserting number into all possible positions of existing permutations

now first loop is clearly `O(n)`

lets see whats happening with other loops:

on final iteration (for worst case):

1. going over all `(n-1)!` permutations (generated with previous iterations) - `O((n-1)!)`
2. copying each of them and adding new number inside - `O(n)` each

in total its `(n-1)! * (n) = n!` for worst case of other loops

so it is `O(n * n!)` overall

Comment: isn't `O(n * n!)` just `O(n!)` in Big O?